# How does start-point work when checking out a new branch in git?

Tags: git

Reading the docs, it looks like this command should give me a branch named `cart` pointing at the HEAD of upstream master:

`git checkout -b cart upstream/master`

However even though I had *just* done a pull from `upstream master` before running that command, after running that command, within the new branch, if I run `git pull upstream master` I get a slew of commits.

So, clearly my starting point was not what I thought it was.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: There's no such thing as "the HEAD of upstream master". `HEAD` is a symbolic reference that points to another branch (usually). Perhaps you meant "the tip"?

Answer (score 1):

Running `git pull upstream master` explicitly does not update any remote-tracking branches. This leaves your `upstream/master` branch alone and containing older data. If you run `git fetch origin`, then `git checkout -b cart upstream/master`, you should find that your new branch is up-to-date.